# file upload in vs code but doesn´t in prompt windows

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, prompt

i run my code in vs code editor and it works, what i do is load a csv file and do some querys, but when i run the code in prompt windows, trows error that the system cant find the file, while in vs code load the file.

here the vs code console.

[image: vs code console]

here the promprt console.

[image: prompt console]

and here is where i have the folders. In data i have the csv file.

[image: Files]

and this is the method where i upload the file:

```
public boolean uploadData() {
try {
  fr = new FileReader(file);
  br = new BufferedReader(fr);
  petsList = new ArrayList<Pet>();
  String line = "";
  // skip headel
  br.readLine();
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] aux = line.split(";");
    try {
      if (aux.length == 6) {
        Pet auxP = new Pet("NO-ID", Long.parseLong(aux[0]), aux[1], aux[2], aux[3], convertToBoolean(aux[4]),
            aux[5]);
        petsList.add(auxP);
      }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      // TODO: handle exception
    }
  }
  b = true;
  return true;
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  return false;
}  }
```

Comment: Is there any differences if you use the absolute path?

Comment: It work, but i dont wanna left the absolute path.

Comment: Check the working directory in VS Code, then turn to the same one in external Terminal. Try again.

Comment: what do you mean?, if you mean check the csv´s path in vs code and the terminal, its the same: C:\Users\<username>\...\pets\data\csv. when i load with the absolute path like u say, it works, but i wanna left the relative path.

Comment: When you run the project in VS Code, there's a directory shown in integrated Terminal , that's your project's current working directory. Turn to the same directory to run the file in external Terminal. that's what i mean.

Comment: ok, y try with the path that have the workSpaceStorage: C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\79c57ca59e9fd0ce6c7f89537a94516a\redhat.java\jdt_ws\work 1_72ef1239\bin' 'App' and didn´t work with the relative path, with the absolute path work.

Comment: Not this path, it should be the directory to your project name, then try again. If it still doesn't work, add a method in your function `UploadData` to parse path to absolute path :`public static String parseHomeDir2AbsDir(String path) {
    String homeDir = System.getProperties().getProperty("user.home");
    return StringUtils.replace(path, "~", homeDir);
}`